# Do I model my training set on real world classification percentages?

Tags: dataset, deep-learning, unbalanced-classes, convolution

NOTE: This is just a toy project - I'm trying to learn by doing. I am aware of the previous work in this area. This question is about how to correctly populate my training, validation and test sets in this specific example.

My goal is to use a CNN to classify images into 3 distinct categories:

```
normal
blurry
highly sharpened
```

I've built the CNN (using Keras) and it is working.

There will be many more `normal` images than `blurry` images. And there will be more `blurry` images than `highly sharpened` images.

Let's assume that 85% of the images will be `normal`, 10% will be `blurry` and 5% will be `highly sharpened`. Does that mean my training/validation/test set should also contain this same percentage breakdown of examples? I don't think it makes sense to just fill each set with ~33% of each class.

Also: this must be incredibly common... is there a Keras/Tensorflow api for this type of partitioning?

Comment: You are dealing with something called as the class imbalance problem. In general your training set should contain similar proportion of classes as you would expect in your test set. Also make sure to use a measure that can handle imbalanced data, e.g. Macro accuracy.

Comment: Thank you @DataD'oh. Is the same also true for the validation and test sets?

Comment: As you are going to tune your model to the validation set, the validation set should have a similar distribution to the (expected) test set. And in turn, your training set distribution should be similar to the validation (and test) set so that a good model (one that performs well on the validation set) can be learned. This is the common case, except when you are dealing with the dataset shift issue, e.g. https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/dataset-shift-machine-learning